# Autozoom / Autocenter with GoogleMaps Avi v3 JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing a code in order to display some pushpins on a maps, using Google Maps V3 APi (JS).

I would like to use Autozoom and Autocenter.
For this, i need to use Bound.extends() and map.fitBounds(), nevertheless, with the use of this functions i have only one pushpins...not the other...it's very strange...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAs4c8xnkxcZNRK6yQt-Y21N1L3mT1AFfE&callback=initMap">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px"></div>

<noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.
</noscript>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

     // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
function createMarker(point,name)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, title: name});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(name);});

    return marker;
}

function initMap() 
{

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));//, { center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},zoom: 8});
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var optionsCarte =  {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.5, 2.9),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), optionsCarte);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // ========== Read paramaters that have been passed in ==========

    // If there are any parameters at the end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
    // looking something like  "?q=My+First+Point@59.591,17.82"

    // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
    var query = location.search.substring(1);

    // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
    var pairs = query.split("&");

    for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) 
    {
        // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
        var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
        var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
        var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);

        // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
        if (argname == "q") 
        {
            var text = unescape(value);
            var parts = text.split("@");

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': parts[1]}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);//center the map over the result

                    var title = parts[0];

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });

            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds)
    map.panToBounds(bounds); 
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

}   

</script>
```

In order to execute my call, i have to do this :

http://XX.XX.XX.XX/MutliMaps.html?q=MyPushPin1@myAdresse1&q=MyPushPin2@myAdresse2

Any idea where is my error? I think it's the bound.extend fonction.

Comment: `bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);` should be inside geocode result function. You probably get an error on browser console.

Comment: Thanks :) it's ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must  move the code related to the bound, zoom and center inside the loop

so you first you have geocode result available (and so you don't get the error for this ) and second you can extend the bound incrementally ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAs4c8xnkxcZNRK6yQt-Y21N1L3mT1AFfE&callback=initMap">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px"></div>

<noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.
</noscript>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

     // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
function createMarker(point,name)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, title: name});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(name);});

    return marker;
}

function initMap() 
{

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));//, { center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},zoom: 8});
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var optionsCarte =  {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.5, 2.9),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), optionsCarte);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // ========== Read paramaters that have been passed in ==========

    // If there are any parameters at the end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
    // looking something like  "?q=My+First+Point@59.591,17.82"

    // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
    var query = location.search.substring(1);

    // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
    var pairs = query.split("&");

    for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) 
    {
        // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
        var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
        var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
        var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);

        // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
        if (argname == "q") 
        {
            var text = unescape(value);
            var parts = text.split("@");

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': parts[1]}, function(results, status) 
            {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
              {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);//center the map over the result

                              var title = parts[0];


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location});

                bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(bounds)
                map.panToBounds(bounds); 
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());               
              } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
              }

            });

            //bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
    }

    //map.fitBounds(bounds)
    ///map.panToBounds(bounds); 
    //map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

}   

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's ok :)